# How to multiplex mp3 and mp4 files in Android

Tags: java, android, mp3, mp4, jcodec

Problem statement:
I am designing an android app in which I have to get images from the user's gallery, combine them to make a video file and add background music. I have used jcodec library to create mp4 video file using my image resources (I know how to get images from gallery and show them in ImageViews and create bitmaps from them). I have a mp4 file. Now, I want to add background music in it using a mp3 file.

Please can anybody help me with this? I cannot add it using jcodec or atleast I don't know how to do that. I can use any library that can do this job but it should be in Java because I don't want to use ndk. I tried ffmpeg and opencv for java but it increased the size of my app by more than 15MB and jcodec has already done half job of making a mp4 file.

I can give you the code that I used to make mp4 file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think `JCODEC` not support add **mp3** in **MP4**.But `JAVACV` Support add **mp3** in **mp4**.

download `JAVACV` from this link https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv.

**this library support Create video from Images and also add mp3 in mp4**.

**code for add mp3 in mp4.**

**Note: it's may not work for create mp4 from JCODEC, create mp4 using JAVACV**

```
FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
            FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(audioPath);
            grabber1.start();
            grabber2.start();
            FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(OutputPath,
                    grabber1.getImageWidth(), grabber1.getImageHeight(), 2);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setVideoQuality(1);
            recorder.setFrameRate(grabber1.getFrameRate());
            recorder.setSampleRate(grabber2.getSampleRate());
            recorder.start();
            Frame frame1, frame2 = null;
            long timestamp = -2;
            int count = 0;
            boolean isFirstTime = false;
            boolean isFirstCheck = true;
            while ((frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame())!=null) {
                //frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame();
                frame2 = grabber2.grabFrame();
                recorder.record(frame1);
                recorder.record(frame2);

                }
            recorder.stop();
            grabber1.stop();
            grabber2.stop();
    } catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I have written in my question that I don't want to use ffmpeg and javacv stuff because it requires a lot of memory footprint. I will try to look for any other technique and if nothing works, I will go with your suggestion. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @SyedZeeshan when you use FFMPEG then it's very difficult to Compile and use in android