# Merging mp4 and mp3 on Android using FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

i am developing a video capturing Android App.
My Goal is to merge the captured Video file with a given mp3 audio file. I am using FFmpeg to merge the files. The capturing is done with the Android.Media Framework. 
If i now try to merge the files like descripted here:

[How to multiplex mp3 and mp4 files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202321/how-to-multiplex-mp3-and-mp4-files-in-android)

i get the error: `avcodec_open2() error -1: Could not open video codec.`

Is there a way to convert the captured video file in a readable version for FFmpeg ?
Or is there any other way to solve this issue ?

i Dont want to capture the video with FFmpeg, caus this will be to much complex and not clean (for my opinion)

Hope that any body can help :)
thanks in advance.

I Capture like propsed in the android DOC:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

and this is how i try to merge

```
    FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
    FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(audioPath);
    grabber1.start();
    grabber2.start();
    FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(OutputPath,grabber1.getImageWidth(), grabber1.getImageHeight(), 2);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setVideoQuality(1);
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber1.getFrameRate());
    recorder.setSampleRate(grabber2.getSampleRate());
    recorder.start();
    Frame frame1, frame2 = null;
    long timestamp = -2;
    int count = 0;
    boolean isFirstTime = false;
    boolean isFirstCheck = true;
    while ((frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame())!=null) {
        //frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame();
        frame2 = grabber2.grabFrame();
        recorder.record(frame1);
        recorder.record(frame2);
    }
    recorder.stop();
    grabber1.stop();
    grabber2.stop();
    }catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```